# Delete files with similar names

Tags: shell, files, filenames, delete

I have been away from scripting for years, so I was wondering if someone can help in the below.

I am migrating from Google Photos to Amazon Photos (about 40k photos). Here is an example of what I downloaded from Google:

```
IMG-20180601-WA0004-modifié.jpg
IMG-20180601-WA0004.jpg
IMG-20180601-WA0004.jpg.json
IMG-20180601-WA0005-modifié.jpg
IMG-20180601-WA0005.jpg
IMG-20180601-WA0005.jpg.json
IMG-20180601-WA0008-modifié.jpg
IMG-20180601-WA0008.jpg
IMG-20180601-WA0008.jpg.json
IMG-20180601-WA0009-modifié.jpg
IMG-20180601-WA0009.jpg
IMG-20180601-WA0009.jpg.json
IMG-20180601-WA0010-modifié.jpg
IMG-20180601-WA0010.jpg
IMG-20180601-WA0010.jpg.json
IMG-20180601-WA0011-modifié.jpg
IMG-20180601-WA0011.jpg
IMG-20180601-WA0011.jpg.json
IMG-20180601-WA0013-modifié.jpg
IMG-20180601-WA0013.jpg
IMG-20180601-WA0013.jpg.json
IMG-20180601-WA0014-modifié.jpg
IMG-20180601-WA0014.jpg
IMG-20180601-WA0014.jpg.json
IMG-20180601-WA0015-modifié.jpg
IMG-20180601-WA0015.jpg
IMG-20180601-WA0015.jpg.json
IMG-20180601-WA0020.jpg
IMG-20180601-WA0020.jpg.json
IMG-20180601-WA0036-modifié.jpg
IMG-20180601-WA0036.jpg
IMG-20180601-WA0036.jpg.json
VID-20180601-WA0012.mp4.json
VID_20180601_195857.mp4.json
métadonnées.json
```

I want the following:

1. Search across all the directories within the main folder of the downloaded photos,
2. delete all the video files such as mov, mp4, mpeg, mpg, avi, m4v and wmv *(note that sometimes the file extension is in caps)*
3. for the photos, you will notice that most of the file names are duplicated (one without the word "modifié" and the other with). Note that not all of them have a "modifié" version, e.g. IMG-20180601-WA0020.jpg. I would like to delete all photos where the filename does not contain the word "modifié" except if the original file does not have a "modifié" version then keep it *(IMG-20180601-WA0020.jpg is an example to keep)*.
4. I prefer to keep the json files as is if they are not related to a video file otherwise delete them.

Comment: Can you please add the script you have so far? Do all the JPG file names end with a number before the suffix?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't say I have a script. All I did was just counting the number of files per extension and then I gave up. I've been away from scripting for more than 15 years now.
Regarding your second question, no necessarily. Here is another example of a filename: 1495267_10203328387516077_910506315287260810_o.jpg in another directory.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting all video files can be accomplished with

```
find . -type f \( -iname '*.mp4' -o -iname '*.mp4.json' \) -delete
```

Add more `-o -iname '*.suffix'` parts for the other suffixes you need.

---

To get rid of the originals for modified pictures, run something like

```
find . -name '*-modifié.jpg' -exec sh -c 'rm -f $(echo "$1" | sed s/-modifié//)' _ {} \;
```

which will find any files with `-modifié` and remove their unmodified version (`rm -f` suppresses an error message in case there is no unmodified version).

PS: I strongly recommend a backup before modifying/running these commands, in case things go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`:

```
zmodload zsh/files # for a builtin rm to avoid the "too many args" limit
                   # of the system one

set -o nocaseglob

echo rm -f -- **/*.(mp4|mpeg|mpg|mov|wmv|avi|m4v)(|.json)(N.)

echo rm -f -- **/*-modifié.jpg(N.e['reply=( ${REPLY%-*}.jpg(|.json)(N.) )'])
```

Remove the `echo`s to actually do it.